# Excel VBA error 1004 when starting macro with alignment code from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, vertical-alignment

the following code gives me error 1004 (*"Unable to set the VerticalAlignment property of the Range class."*) when the macro is started from **Sheet1**:

```
With Sheet2.Cells(1,1)
   .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
End with
```

".Value" or ".FontColor" works good, only this alignment code breaks.
If i start the macro from Sheet2, then no problems at all.
The sheets are password protected, but anyway the macro runs fine when started from Sheet2.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Do you mean [`xlVAlignCenter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.cellformat.verticalalignment)?

Comment: Seems like an issue with the protection - that's the only way I can repro the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Activate to select the sheet before changing the alignment

```
 Worksheets("Worksheet Name").Activate
```

Using "With Sheet2..." should handle the activation however I was getting the same error when assigning properties to a sheet that was not activated. WrapText and RowHeight worked but setting the VerticalAlignment threw the 1004 error.

When I activated the sheet prior to changing the VerticalAlignment worked perfectly.